# Plotting the bifurcation diagram for $\dot\theta=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\mu+\cos(\theta)}$

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

On this site I have found many bifurcation algorithms which work exceptionally well for many cases, but for the following differential equation, they do not seem to work:
$$\dot\theta=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\mu+\cos(\theta)}$$

I got an idea of the bifurcation diagram by drawing it by hand, lines parallel to the $\mu$-axis with holes at $(1,\pi),(0,-\pi),(-1,\pi),$ etc.., but I was looking for something more precise. Can anyone help me create a bifurcation diagram with flow fields?

I was looking something similar to

[image]

Comment: "but for the following differential equation, they do not seem to work" - any code to support that statement?

Comment: This equation can be solved symbolically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting problem.  First, define the right-hand side.

```
f[θ_, μ_] := Sin[θ]/(μ + Cos[θ]);
```

If $|\mu|>1$, there are only the proper equilibria you noted at $\theta=n\pi$:

```
Plot[f[θ, 1.5], {θ, 0, 4 π}, AxesLabel -> {"θ", "θ'"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However if $|\mu|<1$ the denominator might equal zero, resulting in the following:

```
Plot[f[θ, 0.5], {θ, 0, 4 π}, AxesLabel -> {"θ", "θ'"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Those $\theta$ values where the denominator equals zero must also behave like stable equilibria, since $d\theta/dt>0$ below and $d\theta/dt<0$ above.  I'll call them *improper equilibria* for lack of a better term. Any dynamicists please comment on the real name.  They occur at $\theta=arccos(-\mu)$.

The following plots the proper and improper equilibria.  I use linearization to assess the stability of the proper equilibria and just assume the improper ones are stable.  Solid = stable, dashed = unstable.

```
λ[θ_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ] = D[f[θ, μ], θ];
eq = ContourPlot[{
  ConditionalExpression[f[θ, μ], λ[θ, μ] < 0] == 0, 
  ConditionalExpression[f[θ, μ], λ[θ, μ] > 0] == 0,
  (μ + Cos[θ]) == 0}, {μ, -2, 2},
  {θ, -10^-5, 4 π + 10^-5}, ContourStyle -> {Black, {Black, Dashed}},
  MaxRecursion -> 3, FrameLabel -> {μ, θ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, add some flow arrows.

```
streams = VectorPlot[{0, Sign[f[θ, μ]]}, {μ, -2, 2}, {θ, 0, 4 π},
  VectorMarkers -> "Arrow", VectorScale -> Tiny, 
  VectorPoints -> Flatten[Table[{μ, θ}, {μ, -1.8, 1.8, 0.2}, {θ, 0.25 π, 3.75 π, 0.5 π}], 1]];
Show[streams, eq, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 4 π}}, FrameLabel -> {μ, θ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verifying the behavior of the improper equilibria with `NDSolve` requires some trickery.  **Edit:** My previous attempt at getting `NDSolve` to work was wrong, so I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{0, Sin[\[Theta]]/(\[Mu] + Cos[\[Theta]])}, {\[Mu], -3,3},{\[Theta], -Pi, Pi}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction ->"TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {\[Mu], \[Theta]}]
```

[image]